# Where does the compiled code exist in an nx-monorepository

Tags: monorepo, nx-workspace

I am learning to build a monorepository with nx currently and it's going great.

However I am a bit confused about where it actually puts build outputs.
It just seems to work, but not produce any compiled .js files from my .ts files.

The tsconfig.json says the outDir is "../../dist/out-tsc" for my libs, but under that path there is no dist directory.
I've searched my entire workspace and even its parent folder for a "out-tsc" directory and found none.

Where does nx place these files?